# 3 column layout with list items

Tags: html, css, html-lists

```css
.clearself:before,.clearself:after{content: " ";display: block;height: 0;overflow: hidden;}
.clearself:after{clear: both;}
.clearself{zoom: 1;} /* IE < 8 */

ul.three-col-row li{width: 25%;margin-right: 5%;float: left;text-align: center;}
ul.three-col-row li:nth-child(4n+4){margin-right:5%;float: left;} 
ul.three-col-row li:nth-child(3n+3){margin-right: 5%;float: right;} 

.intro{margin:60px 0 0 0;}
.intro h2{margin-bottom: 15px;}
.intro p{margin-bottom: 30px;}
.intro ul.three-col-row li {min-height:310px;}
```

```html
<section class="intro clearself">
      <ul class="three-col-row">
         <li>
          <h2>Wat?..</h2>
          <p>Praktische en juiste informatie is een belangrijke deelsleutel tot de oplossing van rugproblemen.</p>
          <a class="button" href="advice.html">Meer info!</a>
        </li><!-- 
         --><li>
          <h2>Hoe...</h2>
          <p>Ga zo ver mogelijk in de beweging en herhaal dit regelmatig gedurende U capaciteit.</p>
          <a class="button" href="work-out.html">Kies je sport!</a>
        </li><!--
        --><li class="last-row1">
          <h2>Doel...</h2>
          <p>Het belangrijkste aspect is echter dat U ontdekt dat U ZELF veel kan doen om uiteindelijk uw rugklacht te vermijden,meer dan U welicht denkt.</p>
          <a class="button" href="about.html">Meer info!</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

My problem with this is that second column it is not centered correctly. The space between second and third column is too big...My  main content width is 90%, my section min-height is 310px.
When I test the page on Firefox the width of my 3 columns is 275x310px but they still don't look equal. When I test it on Chrome, the width of my 2 columns is 275x310px and the middle one 274x310px.
How can I make the spaces equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you have `float: right` on the third `li`. Make it `float: left` and your margins / gaps will be uniform.

```
ul.three-col-row li:nth-child(3n+3) { margin-right: 5%; float: left; }
```

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/477gg73o/***

---

You could also make use of CSS3 `columns` to make it a little easier.

***Snippet:***

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-columns: 3;
  columns: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 8px;
  column-gap: 8px;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

li {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; 
  column-break-inside: avoid; 
}
```

```html
<section class="intro clearself">
      <ul class="three-col-row">
         <li>
          <h2>Wat?..</h2>
          <p>Praktische en juiste informatie is een belangrijke deelsleutel tot de oplossing van rugproblemen.</p>
          <a class="button" href="advice.html">Meer info!</a>
        </li>
         <li>
          <h2>Hoe...</h2>
          <p>Ga zo ver mogelijk in de beweging en herhaal dit regelmatig gedurende U capaciteit.</p>
          <a class="button" href="work-out.html">Kies je sport!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="last-row1">
          <h2>Doel...</h2>
          <p>Het belangrijkste aspect is echter dat U ontdekt dat U ZELF veel kan doen om uiteindelijk uw rugklacht te vermijden,meer dan U welicht denkt.</p>
          <a class="button" href="about.html">Meer info!</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `display: table-cell` combine with `padding: 0 5% 0 5%` and remove `floats`:

```css
.clearself:before,
.clearself:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.clearself:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearself {
  zoom: 1;
}
/* IE < 8 */

ul.three-col-row li {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
.intro {
  margin: 60px 0 0 0;
}
.intro h2 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.intro p {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  max-height: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
.intro ul.three-col-row li {
  min-height: 310px;
}
ul.three-col-row {
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
  /*remove padding from ul*/
}
ul.three-col-row li {
  display: table-cell;
  /*set display to table-cell*/
  padding: 0px 5% 0 5%;
  /*add padding*/
}
```

```html
<section class="intro clearself">
  <ul class="three-col-row">
    <li>
      <h2>Wat?..</h2>

      <p>Praktische en juiste informatie is een belangrijke deelsleutel tot de oplossing van rugproblemen.</p> <a class="button" href="advice.html">Meer info!</a>

    </li>
    <!-- -->
    <li>
      <h2>Hoe...</h2>

      <p>Ga zo ver mogelijk in de beweging en herhaal dit regelmatig gedurende U capaciteit.</p> <a class="button" href="work-out.html">Kies je sport!</a>

    </li>
    <!-- -->
    <li class="last-row1">
      <h2>Doel...</h2>

      <p>Het belangrijkste aspect is echter dat U ontdekt dat U ZELF veel kan doen om uiteindelijk uw rugklacht te vermijden,meer dan U welicht denkt.</p> <a class="button" href="about.html">Meer info!</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: It's working like this,but not for responsive layout.

Comment: hmmm don't see the issue you describe.

Comment: I can not put a picture to show where the problem is.the problem is that the columns should be responsive. And on a small screen should colums be under eachother. If I use display: table than on the big screen is perfect, but on mobile site does not show below the other.

Answer (score 0):

I added a main-content div and edited/removed some CSS code. Hope this helps.

```css
.clearself:before,.clearself:after{content: " ";display: block;height: 0;overflow: hidden;}
.clearself:after{clear: both;}
.clearself{zoom: 1;} /* IE < 8 */

ul.three-col-row li{width: 29%;float: left;text-align: center;margin: 0 2% 0 2%;}

.intro{margin:60px 0 0 0;}
.intro h2{margin-bottom: 15px;}
.intro p{margin-bottom: 30px;}
.intro ul.three-col-row li {min-height:310px;}
.main-content-box {width: 90%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;position:relative;}
```

```html
<section class="intro clearself">
   <div class="main-content-box">
      <ul class="three-col-row">
         <li>
          <h2>Wat?..</h2>
          <p>Praktische en juiste informatie is een belangrijke deelsleutel tot de oplossing van rugproblemen.</p>
          <a class="button" href="advice.html">Meer info!</a>
        </li><!-- 
         --><li>
          <h2>Hoe...</h2>
          <p>Ga zo ver mogelijk in de beweging en herhaal dit regelmatig gedurende U capaciteit.</p>
          <a class="button" href="work-out.html">Kies je sport!</a>
        </li><!--
        --><li class="last-row1">
          <h2>Doel...</h2>
          <p>Het belangrijkste aspect is echter dat U ontdekt dat U ZELF veel kan doen om uiteindelijk uw rugklacht te vermijden,meer dan U welicht denkt.</p>
          <a class="button" href="about.html">Meer info!</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </section>
```